# MYSQL development workflow with git versioned scripts

Tags: git, mysql

I'm sure that similar workflows are common, but in my searching I have not found any documented examples.

**Goals:**

1. I want to manage all of a mysql (v5.1+) database definition in
   git, so that I have all of the benefits of source control.
2. I want to define changes to the database by editing the scripts, and
   running the scripts, so that I can edit the database definition in
   my editor of choice (vim), rather than the mysql shell, or a gui
   app.

Aside: I currently use the mysql shell, but would like to use vim to maintain routines and events which becomes unwieldy in the shell.

**Plan:**

I will do an initial dump with the '--no-data' option to get my initial scripts, but from then on I want  my workflow to be: edit scripts -> commit -> run scripts rather than: perform change to database -> dump ddl -> commit.

**Caveats:**

If I dump the database with the following:

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [password] --no-data --routines > ddl.sql
```

It includes:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `[table]`; CREATE TABLE `[table]` ([table definition])
```

Obviously that will destroy, and recreate the table if I run the script.
What I would like to do is update the table with definition changes if the table exists, otherwise create the table with the definition.  I would prefer to define the table in one [table]([table dfinition]) block, that is re-used, than to have to maintain multiple duplicate blocks.

How would I change the initial dump syntax, or the scripts, so that I can use the same scripts to update the database, and re-create the database definition (without data) in another environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, just `mysqldump`ing does not work for this.

Generally, you need to store the changes to the database structure. So instead of storing:

```
// commit 1
// foo.sql
CREATE TABLE foo ( foo_id INT );

// commit 2
// foo.sql
CREATE TABLE foo ( foo_id INT, foo_val INT );
```

You should store something more like:

```
// commit 1
// foo_1.sql
CREATE TABLE foo ( foo_id INT );

// commit 2
// foo_2.sql
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN ( foo_val INT );
```

Then, you should have a script that can run

- foo_1.sql
- foo_2.sql

in the right order.

You would be even better off to write scripts that have up() and down() options, so your migrations can be run **forwards** (build table, add column) and **backwards** (drop column, drop table).

You just have to remember to run the **backwards** scripts *before* you check out a branch that relies on the db change.